# Excel rows with multiple lines in one

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I've created a Workbook to show an excel with different contents. That excel has some rows that contain some lines each. The problem is the excel only has that format when I click in a specific row and I want the entire excel looks like that.

This is my code:

```
Workbook worbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
Sheet sheet = worbook.createSheet("Publication List");
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
Locale locale = resourceResponse.getLocale();
Font headerFont = worbook.createFont();
headerFont.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 11);
headerFont.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
headerFont.setColor(new HSSFColor.DARK_BLUE().getIndex());
CellStyle headerStyle = worbook.createCellStyle();
headerStyle.setFont(headerFont);
headerStyle.setWrapText(true);
headerStyle.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
headerStyle.setFillForegroundColor(new HSSFColor.GREY_25_PERCENT().getIndex());

try {
    List < Country > countries = CountryServiceUtil.getCountries();

    if (allRequests != null) {
        int columnHeader = 0;
        Row rowHead = sheet.createRow(0);

        for (String headerColumn: header) {
            Cell cell = rowHead.createCell(columnHeader);
            cell.setCellValue(LanguageUtil.get(locale, headerColumn));
            cell.setCellStyle(headerStyle);
            columnHeader++;
        }

        int requestRow = 1;
        for (PublicationRequest publication: allRequests) {
            Row rowsBody = sheet.createRow(requestRow);
            Country country = CountryServiceUtil.fetchCountryByA2(publication.getCountry());
            String fullAddress = publication.getAddress() + StringPool.RETURN_NEW_LINE + publication.getCp() + StringPool.SPACE + publication.getCity() + StringPool.RETURN_NEW_LINE + country.getName();

            rowsBody.createCell(8).setCellValue(fullAddress);

            //Publication items. Cell 8
            long scopeGroupId = PortalUtil.getScopeGroupId(resourceRequest);
            List < PublicationRequestItem > allRequestItems = PublicationRequestItemLocalServiceUtil.findBypublicationRequestId(publication.getPublicationRequestId());
            String publicationsVocabulary = PrefsParamUtil.getString(resourceRequest.getPreferences(), resourceRequest, "publicationsVocabulary", "");
            AssetVocabulary publicationsTypeVocabulary = null;
            if (Validator.isNotNull(publicationsVocabulary)) {

                try {
                    publicationsTypeVocabulary = AssetVocabularyLocalServiceUtil.getAssetVocabularyByUuidAndGroupId(publicationsVocabulary, scopeGroupId);
                    String category = StringPool.BLANK;
                    for (PublicationRequestItem item: allRequestItems) {
                        JournalArticle latestArticle;
                        latestArticle = JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.getLatestArticle(scopeGroupId, item.getArticleId());
                        if (!category.equals(StringPool.BLANK)) {
                            category = category + StringPool.NEW_LINE;
                        }

                        category += RequestDisplayUtil.getPublicationTitle(locale, latestArticle, publicationsTypeVocabulary);
                    }

                    rowsBody.createCell(9).setCellValue(category);
                } catch (PortalException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            requestRow++;

        }

        for (int column = 0; column < columnHeader + 1; column++) {
            sheet.autoSizeColumn(column);
        }
    }
} catch (SystemException e) {
    _log.error("Error while creating Excel file", e);
} catch (PortalException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

resourceResponse.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
resourceResponse.setProperty("expires", "-1d");
resourceResponse.setProperty("Pragma", "no-cache");
resourceResponse.setProperty(HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL, "no-cache");
```

I've tried as well with char(10) but I get the same end

Thank you

Comment: any chance you are reusing the headerStyle and setting wrapText to false later on?

Comment: The only  thing I use It's autoSizeColum, but I think does not matters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got a solution.

I only was giving styles to the header cells:

```
for (String headerColumn: header) {
    Cell cell = rowHead.createCell(columnHeader);
    cell.setCellValue(LanguageUtil.get(locale, headerColumn));
    cell.setCellStyle(headerStyle);
    columnHeader++;
```

I had to create the body cells previously and give it some style:

```
rowsBody.createCell(8).getCellStyle().setWrapText(true);
rowsBody.getCell(8).setCellValue(fullAddress);
```